# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on php 5.3.6

Tags: php, syntax

I am having problem with `php` version. My server only uses `php` 5.3.6 but my website files require `php` 5.4 and above.

Is there a way to convert the below code to be accepted by `php` 5.3.6?

```
$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )**[0]**;


<?php       
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

        $post_meta = $Listing->get_listing_meta(get_the_ID());
        $listing_options = (isset($post_meta['listing_options']) && !empty($post_meta['listing_options']) ? $post_meta['listing_options'] : "");
        $gallery_images  = (isset($post_meta['gallery_images']) && !empty($post_meta['gallery_images']) ? $post_meta['gallery_images'] : "");

        $thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )[0];
```

Comment: post the full code, it say missing [, more like syntax problem not related to version problem.

Comment: It says "unexpected" and not "missing". There is some difference if you find an unexpected woman in your bed or you are missing your wife. PHP 5.4 Introduced some array shorthands, so this actually could be a version problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`$thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' )[0];`

use

```
$thumbnails = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
$thumbnail = $thumbnails[0];
```

Good luck! =)

Answer (score 0):

`$thumbnail = array_shift(wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ));`
would return the first element of an array for you, but are you sure that your Hoster does not offer PHP > 5.3?
5.3 is very old and even reached its "end of life". You could get more errors/incompatibilities in your code when using untested PHP version

Comment: Hi, i agree to what you said. have advised my client to upgrade the server or change hosting provider. as final decision is with them. i have to find work around. thanks for great help it works great

Answer (score 0):

Function [array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) was introduced in php 5.4.0

Previous versions will give you syntax errors, such as in your case.

Either upgrade the php version to >= 5.4.0 or change the code to remove the dereferencing.

Example for your case:

```
$thumbnail_temp = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
$thumbnail = $thumbnail_temp[0];
```

More about [array dereferencing in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-105).

Comment: thanks for the proper introduction to array dereferencing. now i understand whats going on. its now working thanks for great advise!

Comment: @NigelOng you are very welcome!